# Deploy error on persistence.xml Jboss 6.x + jpa

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm trying create a webapp with jpa under jboss, but when i'm running the app occurs error in the server deploy.

I'm using eclipse luna and I have added jpa support in project properties (Project Faces), in the wizard I have marked to not generate the persistence.xml file, to work only with annotations. But the server deploy fail.

What can I do?

[image]

I took some parts of the trace to fit in the post

```
01:00:41,344 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
01:00:45,590 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
01:00:45,613 WARN  [AbstractKernelController] Broken callback: ClassSingleCallbackItem@1c6db9f5{name=interface org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor whenRequired=ControllerState@501dc938{Installed} dependentState=ControllerState@501dc938{Installed} attributeName=setProcessor owner=AbstractKernelControllerContext@550b7a01{ metadata=AbstractBeanMetaData@65f8dd6d{name=JMSDescriptorDeployer bean=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer properties= classLoader=BeanMetaDataDeployer$DeploymentClassLoaderMetaData@2934fa09{classloader=null} constructor=null autowireCandidate=true installCallbacks=[method=setProcessor, method=setParser]}name=JMSDescriptorDeployer target=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer@67cb9267 state=Installed depends=AbstractDependencyInfo@35915368{}} signature=org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.jms.WebservicesDescriptorProcessorImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessor
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer.setProcessor(JMSDescriptorDeployer.java:33) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ClassSingleCallbackItem.ownerCallback(ClassSingleCallbackItem.java:78) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1887) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1937) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1092) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [:1.7.0_45]

01:00:45,749 WARN  [AbstractKernelController] Broken callback: ClassSingleCallbackItem@167e01ff{name=interface org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor whenRequired=ControllerState@501dc938{Installed} dependentState=ControllerState@501dc938{Installed} attributeName=setProcessor owner=AbstractKernelControllerContext@2fed0cb8{ metadata=AbstractBeanMetaData@6c16e441{name=WSDescriptorDeployer bean=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer properties= classLoader=BeanMetaDataDeployer$DeploymentClassLoaderMetaData@4bc7e296{classloader=null} constructor=null autowireCandidate=true installCallbacks=[method=setProcessor, method=setParser]}name=WSDescriptorDeployer target=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer@586ecd2c state=Installed depends=AbstractDependencyInfo@52e39ed7{}} signature=org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessorImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.WebservicesDescriptorProcessor
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer.setProcessor(WSDescriptorDeployer.java:33) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.SingleCallbackItem.changeCallback(SingleCallbackItem.java:67) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractCallbackItem.changeCallback(AbstractCallbackItem.java:80) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.OwnerCallbackItem.changeCallback(OwnerCallbackItem.java:116) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1951) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1092) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [:1.7.0_45]

01:00:46,571 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]
01:00:49,909 Advertência [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
01:00:52,345 Advertência [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
01:00:52,499 INFO  [JMXConnector] starting JMXConnector on host localhost:1090
01:00:52,634 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
01:00:53,302 Informações [HornetQServerImpl] live server is starting..
01:00:53,362 INFO  [JournalStorageManager] Using NIO Journal
01:00:53,383 Advertência [HornetQServerImpl] Security risk! It has been detected that the cluster admin user and password have not been changed from the installation default. Please see the HornetQ user guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to do this.
01:00:53,990 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 localhost:5455 for CORE protocol
01:00:53,991 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 localhost:5445 for CORE protocol
01:00:53,994 Informações [HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.1.2.Final (Colmeia, 120) started
01:00:54,037 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://localhost:8083/
01:00:54,186 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32010 JBossTS Recovery Service (tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc.
01:00:54,191 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12324 Start RecoveryActivators
01:00:54,203 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12296 ExpiredEntryMonitor running at Qui, 4 Jun 2015 01:00:54
01:00:54,250 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12310 Recovery manager listening on endpoint 127.0.0.1:4712
01:00:54,251 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12344 RecoveryManagerImple is ready on port 4712
01:00:54,252 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32013 Starting transaction recovery manager
01:00:54,258 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12163 Starting service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 4713
01:00:54,259 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12337 TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 127.0.0.1 port: 4713
01:00:54,303 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12170 TransactionStatusManager started on port 4713 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
01:00:54,330 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32017 JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc.
01:00:54,370 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12202 registering bean jboss.jta:type=ObjectStore.
01:00:54,592 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/bin/native
01:00:54,704 INFO  [ModClusterService] Initializing mod_cluster 1.1.0.Final
01:00:54,718 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker
01:00:55,009 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
01:00:55,019 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
01:00:55,025 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
01:00:55,035 INFO  [HornetQResourceAdapter] HornetQ resource adaptor started
01:00:55,040 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
01:00:55,050 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/D:/Projetos/AngularJS/PlataformDesenv/runtimes/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
01:00:55,122 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: Thread-2
01:00:55,147 INFO  [SchedulerSignalerImpl] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
01:00:55,147 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.3 created.
01:00:55,149 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
01:00:55,150 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler 
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to resolve Java binding for /D:/Projetos/EclipseWeb/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1433385246628/deploy/TTTTTT.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml (check the SchemaBinding resolver configuration)
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:259) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:352) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:334) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:251) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:369) [:2.2.0.GA]
    ... 74 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue.
[Here a solution](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/195264) (original message, karluqs Aug 8, 2012 1:02 PM)

**Solution from karluqs:**

> I dont know whats exactly causing the classcastexception, but i made a
> change in
> JBOSS_HOME/server//deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/stack-agnostic-jboss-beans.xml.
>
> For the beans WSDescriptorDeployer and JMSDescriptorDeployer,
> commented the setProcessor incallback and putted the exact bean
> directly

```xml
<!-- deployers -->
<bean name="WSDescriptorDeployer" class="org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer">
    <!-- <incallback method="setProcessor"/> -->
    <property name="processor">
        <inject bean="WSDescriptorProcessor" />
    </property>
    <incallback method="setParser" />
</bean>
...
<bean name="JMSDescriptorDeployer" class="org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer">
    <!-- <incallback method="setProcessor"/> -->
    <property name="processor">
        <inject bean="CXFJMSDescriptorProcessor" />
    </property>
    <incallback method="setParser" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **do** need a `persistence.xml` to define your persistence units, even if you rely on annotations to define your entities etc.

From the JPA 2.1 spec (available for download [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)):

> Each persistence unit deployed into a Java EE container consists of a
>   single `persistence.xml` file, any number of mapping files, and any
>   number of class files.

Comment: I have added the persistence.xml and the same error occur. I think that my problema not is in xml file.